# Setting incoming Json data as Unix Timestamp to nullable

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I have to convert the data I get through the API and that's why I couldn't set it to nullable.

```
var releaseDateTime =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(_data.releaseDate! * 1000);
String releaseDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(releaseDateTime);

Text(releaseDate),
```

But the incoming data may come as null or "0". So,

How can I print "N/A" in case of null or "0" depending on the condition.

Comment: `_data.releaseDate` is the data that you receive from API?

Comment: Yes it's coming from API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check value before pass data in `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()`

check below sample :

```dart
String releaseDate = "N/A"

if(_data.releaseDate != null && _data.releaseDate != "0"){
var releaseDateTime =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(_data.releaseDate! * 1000);
 releaseDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(releaseDateTime);
}

Text(releaseDate),
```

Comment: Thanks you very much it worked. There is one more data I have to convert and it can only come as null. Since the data comes as a String, I convert it to a double value and convert it as toStringAsFixed. Can i handle this inside the parentheses or do i have to write a separate if loop. Sorry to keep you busy, I'm just trying to learn the intricacies of dart.  
This is model:  var _savings = double.parse(_data.savings!); Text(_savings.toStringAsFixed),